# Ruby Gem Sequel - how to show only group by with count value > 1

Tags: ruby, sequel

With

```
DB[:items].group_and_count(:name).all
```

I get a list of names with the number of occurances.

What do I need to do if I only want those names returned (incluing their count) that have a count of more than e.g. 2?
In SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT name, count(name) FROM items GROUP BY name HAVING count(name) > 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this?

```
DB[:items].group('name').having('COUNT(name) > 2')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Almstost, had to use  
DB[:items].group('name').having{COUNT(name) > 2'}
to get it working.

Comment: @Muhammedogz yeah, I edited my answer! 

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the having clause, that can be done in more than one way in Sequel.

```rb
# This uses virtual row as it is called in Sequel, with the { and }
DB[:items].group_and_count(:name).having{Sequel.function(:count, :name) > 2}.all

# or like this if you prefer
DB[:items].group_and_count(:name).having{COUNT(name) > 2}.all
```